# How to Print the backtrace of the fucntion call suquence in Cobalt with QA version?

Tags: cobalt

The `base::debug::StackTrace` can NOT print the `Backtrace` of function call sequence neither by the interface `PrintBacktrace()` or `OutputToStream()` with Cobalt QA version, so is there a way to print the backtrace with Cobalt QA version?

Comment: It runs cobalt QA version in ARM linux platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `src/base/debug/stack_trace_starboard.cc`, `StackTrace::PrintBacktrace()` passes the stack into a `PrintBacktraceOutputHandler`, which ultimately outputs to `SbLogRaw()`, which in `src/starboard/shared/posix/log_raw.cc` should `write()` to `STDERR_FILENO`, regardless of build type.

When I try this in linux-x64x11_qa Cobalt:

```
base::debug::StackTrace().PrintBacktrace();
LOG(INFO) << base::debug::StackTrace().ToString();
```

I get two stack traces printed:

```
    SbEventHandle [0x4158e4]
    starboard::shared::starboard::Application::DispatchStart() [0x4933b8]
    starboard::shared::starboard::Application::Run() [0x49330e]
    main [0x48c248]
    <unknown> [0x7f272613cf45]
    <unknown> [0x4156b9]
    <unknown> [0x4156b9]
[0113/132642:INFO:main.cc(37)] SbEventHandle [0x415950]
    starboard::shared::starboard::Application::DispatchStart() [0x4933b8]
    starboard::shared::starboard::Application::Run() [0x49330e]
    main [0x48c248]
    <unknown> [0x7f272613cf45]
    <unknown> [0x4156b9]
    <unknown> [0x4156b9]
```

Since this ultimately writes out to `SbLogRaw()`, I'd look at how that is behaving in QA builds to see what your problem is.

Comment: I checked the code again with your clue, and changed the write fucntion to fprintf , and it can print the log to the console now, may be the system has not redirected the output of the write fucntion to console yet. Thanks so much for your kind help!